# Apply cart discount if customer collects in store

Tags: shipping, discount

My customer with Magento Community 1.7 would like to apply a discount to the total order value if the customer collects in their physical store.

So, they have the normal shipping rates, but if the customer selects 'Collect in Store' then they get eg 5% off the total.

Most things I have seen allow the shipping rates to be varied, but if the rate is already 0 how could a discount be applied?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a salesrule which checks for a specific shipping method.

[image: preview shipping rule]

As you can clearly see, you can create rules for a specific shipping method.
The action would be 5% discount.